The Proof of the Model Existence Lemma and Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem
Model Existence Lemma: given a consistent set of sentences $S$ in the language $L$, there is a model of $S$.
I'm sure this is just a silly confusion. The usual proof of the Model Existence Lemma requires us to construct a complete, consistent, witnessing extension of $S$. If $S$ was to contain Peano Arithmetic $(\textbf{PA})$, would we not be building a complete and consistent extension of $\textbf{PA}$, contradicting Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem?

We would, but GIT doesn’t prohibit that. There are no complete, consistent recursively axiomatizable extensions of PA. (There are continuum-many complete, consistent extensions.)

I don't understand why this got a downvote, it's a reasonable and common confusion. (It is a duplicate, but that's not the same as warranting downvotes.)
